# Passar variável do php pelo javascript e depois pegar no php via post

Tags: php, javascript

Bom, tenho uma variável PHP uma uma página index.php. E ao clicar, carrego outra parte da página dentro de uma div com javascript.
Ao carregar a página, a variável da index não é reconhecida dentro da pagina da div (que também é .php).

```
<?php
$variavel = 1234;
?>


<script>
function carregar(pagina){
    $("#conteudo").load(pagina);
}
</script>



<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="nav-item">

<a class="nav-link active"   onclick="carregar('includes/graficos/pesoaluno.php')" href="#">Registro de peso</a>

</li>

</ul>

<div id="conteudo"></div>
```

Comment: Pode passar para uma variável `Javascript` assim: `var x = '<?php echo $variavel;?>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bem simples imprima sua variavel dentro do script passando como parameto `$_GET`

veja o exemplo abaixo

```
<script>
function carregar(pagina){
    $("#conteudo").load(pagina+"?pegaAqui=<?php echo $variavel; ?>");
}
</script>
```

...

```
<a class="nav-link active"             onclick="carregar('includes/graficos/pesoaluno.php')" href="#">Registro de peso</a>
```

Agora dentro da sua pagina 
pesoaluno.php 
você receberá a variavel da seguinte forma

```
<?php
   echo $_GET['pegaAqui'];
?>
```

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado!